# How accurate is the elliptic integral solution of simple pendulum?

Tags: experimental-physics, friction, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, error-analysis

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Arbitrary-amplitude_period) indicates the exact solution to the simple pendulum period oscillation [can be written using elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind).

Can anyone tell me if experiments have been carried out (some links with tables) to show what is the accordance with this formula?

Answer (score 1):

The "high school solution" of the pendulum is obtained replacing $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$ for small $\theta$. If you avoid this simplification by solving the full dynamics, you obtain an exact solution that captures the non-isochronicity of the pendulum for large angles.

The main missing ingredient in is solution is now the dissipative component, like viscous friction from the air or the friction in the bolt. These couple to the pendulum mass altering the frequency to some extent and becoming the main source of uncertainty. However, as they depend on the specific setup (and note that they may be well negligible), it is impossible to give a "universal table".

What one could do is to include the dissipative terms (at least by switching to numerical integration). At that point the model gets probably enough degrees of freedom (gravity, length, mass and various friction coefficients) to be fitted to the data from a real pendulum obtaining agreement beyond the precision of whatever instrument.

Comment: you missed my question, Dario. I am not asking for universal tables. The naive formula is accurate only up to 10 - 15 °. If you consider a greater angle say 45° or 90° you need some correction. Various [approximations](https://hal9k.ifsc.usp.br/~matias/disciplinas/grad/2007-Fisica-Computacional-I/lista06/Lima.pdf) have been proposed. I am asking how accurately the *Jacobi integral* follows the actual periods, considering the due influence of friction. Can you quote just one single experiment with an angle greater than 1 radian?

Comment: not considering Jacobi (which I can find with on-line calculators), do you know where to trace a serious  by* serious* I mean with a long rod and heavy weight) experiment which establishes the actual period for angles greater than 1 radian?